# How to add a custom extension to an access package policy

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing a script to create a new access package in my tenant and have a hit a brick wall in how to add custom extensions to an access policy.

Below is an abbreviated version of what I've got so far. Once created I can edit the policy through the browser and set the extension to run at the approval granted/removed stage but haven't been able to figure out how to do it through PowerShell. Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

```
// create catalog
$catalog = New-MgEntitlementManagementCatalog -DisplayName "..." -Description "..." -IsExternallyVisible

// add custom extension to catalog
$params = @{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.accessPackageAssignmentRequestWorkflowExtension"
    displayName = "..."
    description = "..."
    endpointConfiguration = @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.logicAppTriggerEndpointConfiguration"
        subscriptionId = $subscriptionId
        resourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName
        logicAppWorkflowName = $logicAppWorkflowName
    }
    authenticationConfiguration = @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.azureAdPopTokenAuthentication"
    }
    callbackConfiguration = @{
        "@odata.type" = "microsoft.graph.customExtensionCallbackConfiguration"
        durationBeforeTimeout = "PT1H"
    }
}

$extension = New-MgEntitlementManagementCatalogCustomWorkflowExtension -AccessPackageCatalogId $catalog.Id -BodyParameter $params

// create access package
$params = @{
    displayName = "..."
    description = "..."
    isHidden = $false
    catalog = @{
        id = $catalog.Id
    }
}

$accessPackage = new-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage -BodyParameter $params

// create policy
$params = @{
    displayName = "..."
    description = "..."
    allowedTargetScope = "specificConnectedOrganizationUsers"
    specificAllowedTargets = @(
        @{
            "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.connectedOrganizationMembers"
            connectedOrganizationId = $organisation.Id
        }
    )
    expiration = @{
        endDateTime = $null
        duration = "P365D"
        type = "afterDuration"
    }
    requestorSettings = @{
        enableTargetsToSelfAddAccess = $true
        enableTargetsToSelfUpdateAccess = $false
        enableTargetsToSelfRemoveAccess = $true
        allowCustomAssignmentSchedule = $false
        enableOnBehalfRequestorsToAddAccess = $false
        enableOnBehalfRequestorsToUpdateAccess = $false
        enableOnBehalfRequestorsToRemoveAccess = $false
        onBehalfRequestors = @()
    }
    requestApprovalSettings = @{
        isApprovalRequiredForAdd = $true
        isApprovalRequiredForUpdate = $false
        stages = @(
            @{
                durationBeforeAutomaticDenial = "P7D"
                isApproverJustificationRequired = $false
                isEscalationEnabled = $false
                durationBeforeEscalation = "P5D"
                primaryApprovers = @(
                    @{
                        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.internalSponsors"
                    }
                )
                escalationApprovers = @()
                fallbackEscalationApprovers = @()
            }
        )
    }
    questions = @(
        @{
            "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.accessPackageTextInputQuestion"
            isRequired = $true
            isAnswerEditable = $true
            text = "Forename"
            sequence = "0"
            isSingleLineQuestion =$true
        }
        @{
            "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.accessPackageTextInputQuestion"
            isRequired = $true
            isAnswerEditable = $true
            text = "Surname"
            sequence = "1"
            isSingleLineQuestion =$true
        }
    )
    accessPackage = @{
        id = $accessPackage.Id
    }
}

$policy = New-MgEntitlementManagementAssignmentPolicy -BodyParameter $params
```